# How to echo class name from number in MySql table by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I hope you good! I real need help on My PHP scrip:
I have two classes from different files and HTML form as shown below.

1: registerForm.php

This form used to collect information from user, I will show you some of fields  and codes

```
  <div class="form_sep">
     <label for="reg_input_name" class="req">Class:</label>
     <select name="class" id="class" class="form-control" data- 
     required="true">
      <option>Select class</option>
       <option value="1">Baby</option>
       <option value="2">Middle</option>
       <option value="3">Pre-unity</option>
       <option value="4">Grade one</option>
       <option value="6">Grade three</option>
       <option value="7">Grade four</option>
       <option value="8">Grade five</option>
       <option value="9">Grade six</option>
       <option value="10">Grade seven</option>
       </select></div>
```

As you can see above, when user select, lets say "Grade five", number 8 will be saved to the table, currently on the browser it shows number as class value on studentReg.php file, but I want to convert/return those numbers into their class name so that user to see Grade one, Grade two, Grade three and so on.

2: Thiss is course.php class file:

```
   <?php
     include_once("class.database.php"); 
   function selectStdreg()
    {
    $org_id = $_SESSION['org_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student_reg WHERE org_id ='$org_id'";
    $result = $this->database->query($sql);
    $result = $this->database->result;
    $this->rows = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $this->rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $this->rows;
   }
      ?>
```

3: This is student_controller.php class file for returning number to class name

```
 <?php

include_once("class.database.php");

 class student_controller
 {

  public static function admittedClax($jibu)

 {
        if ($jibu == 1) {
            return "Baby";
        } else if ($jibu == 2) {
            return "Middle";
        } else if ($jibu == 3) {
            return "Pre-unit";
        } else if ($jibu == 4) {
            return "Grade one";
        } else if ($jibu == 5) {
            return "Grade two";
        } else if ($jibu == 6) {
            return "Grade three";
        } else if ($jibu == 7) {
            return "Grade four";
        } else if ($jibu == 8) {
            return "Grade five";
        } else if ($jibu == 9) {
            return "Grade six";
        } else if ($jibu == 10) {
            return "Grade seven";
        } else {
            return "no such class";
        }

      }

   }

 ?>
```

4: This is header.php file for creating objects

```
 <?php
  require_once("class/class.course.php");
  require_once("class/class.std_category.php");
  require_once("class/class.studentReg.php");
  require_once("class/class.student_controller.php");
  // objects
  $courseObj=new course;
  $std_categoryObj=new std_category;
  $studentAdmitObj=new studentReg;
  $stdController = new student_controller;
 ?>
```

5: studentReg.php file which used to display student informations

```
    <?php
   include('inc/header.php');

  $stdcategorylist=$courseObj->selectStdreg($jibu);
  if(count($stdcategorylist)>0)
 {?>
    <div id="" style="display: flex; height: 180px; width: auto; overflow:    
   scroll" >
    <table id="resp_table" class="table toggle-square" data-  
   filter="#table_search" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th data-toggle="true">Add_Date</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Nationality</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Birth Date</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Gender</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Religion</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Class</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Trans Route</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Health</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Father Name</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Occupation</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Office Adress</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Mobile</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Mother Name</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Occupation</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Office adress</th>
        <th data-toggle="true">Mobile</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php echo $nana = $stdController->admittedClax($jibu);  ?>

    <?php foreach($stdcategorylist as $list)   {?>
   <tr style="width: 100%">
    <td><?php echo $list->add_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->country; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->b_date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->gender; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->religion; ?></td>

    // Am stacking here on this field       
    <td><?php echo $list->class; ?></td>


    <td><?php echo $list->roote; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->h_prob; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_one; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_oneoccup; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_oneofc; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_onemob; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_two; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_two_occup; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_two_offc; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list->pname_two_mob; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>

    </tbody></div>
    <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-sm"></ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
 <?php } ?>
```

NOTE: for now what I get after echo $nana is no such class

Any one who have idea on how to combine / join above classes so as to get desired answer I will appreciate, and Am very sorry for many explanations and my English.

Comment: Where do you set `$jibu` in `studentReg.php`?

Comment: ?? before this line `<?php echo $nana = $stdController->admittedClax($jibu);  ?>`

Comment: I just forget that sorry, but what ever I put that it will not show what I want